# Hirsute/Impish - Laptop backlight brightness not controllable with nvidia-drivers-470

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness, backlight

I updated my nVidia drivers from 460 to 470 in order to use GloriousEggroll's fork of Proton with Steam. Since then, my laptop's brightness has been stuck on full. The GUI brightness control slides but has no effect. Manually `echo`ing a value into `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia0/brightness` also has no effect (though shows the value has changed when `cat`'d).

I was running Hirsute on kernel 5.11.0-38. I have since upgraded to Impish on kernel 5.13.0-20 and the issue remains. Since upgrading, it seems I can't roll back to nvidia-460 as it is now a link to 470. The Fn+F3/4 hotkeys have never worked on this laptop but I generally scroll the mouse on the battery widget in Cinnamon.

I have tried `acpi.backlight=vendor` and `video.use_native_backlight=1` as kernel flags with no effect. `xbacklight` and `light` also have no effect despite showing the value changing.

Hardware is an Aorus X7 DT v8 with nVidia Geforce GTX 1080m GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after waiting long enough, `nvidia-495` made it into the Impish repos. I just upgraded my nVidia drivers from 470 to 495 and it did the trick - I have brightness control again on reboot.